# Glassfish where do I set classloader delegate option to false

Tags: java, glassfish

I have a web application (running on glassfisch 3.1.2) where I'm facing ClassCastException. I would like to try to solve them by setting the classloader delegate to false.
I'm not able to figure out where (what file) to insert following xml tag

```
<class-loader delegate="false" />
```

Google says to put that to glassfish-web.xml but I haven't got any such a file in my project (Netbeans 8.0.1) nor on server installation...
Can some direct me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The file has to be in the `WEB-INF` folder.

In NetBeans you can right-click the `WEB-INF` folder, choose `New` and `Glassfish Descriptor`. This should automatically create the correct file.

If this doesn't work, you can just create a new xml file in this folder. It has to look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="false"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: I have a similar problem but I need to do this in EJB, I am using Glassfish 4. How to achieve this? can you please help?