# JSON response in REST API and Glassfish

Tags: java, rest, glassfish

I have a REST API that returns a JSON response, but when I deployed it on Glassfish, it keeps giving me an Exception of class not found as below:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException not found by org.eclipse.persistence.moxy
```

based on the suggested fix is to replace the MOXy JAR inside the Glassfish modules folder, but I am wondering if there is a better solution without touching this folder.

Comment: Which version of GF are you using? What kind of application? Is it a WAR file?

Comment: 4.1.2 and yes it is a war

Comment: Googling for your error message and checking the available options I think replacing the JAR file is the best option if you are stuck to that old Glassfish version.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking a little further about your problem, another solution comes to my mind. I haven't tested it but you might give it a shot.

1. Download the JAR where the problem is fixed.
   http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy/2.6.1/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.6.1.jar
2. Package the JAR into your application. I assume this has to go into `WEB-INF/lib` of your WAR file.
3. Disable classloader delegation in `glassfish-web.xml` of your application. Here is a description how to do it: [Glassfish where do I set classloader delegate option to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475192/glassfish-where-do-i-set-classloader-delegate-option-to-false)
   This causes Glassfish to first look into your `WEB-INF/lib` when searching for classes. So you *might* get around your problem.