# Force jar loading in GlassFish

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, resteasy, glassfish-3

Our web app use **RestEasy** (specifically version **3.0.10.Final**).
The problem is that, when we use the **javax.ws.rs.core.Response** class located at **jaxrs-api-3.0.10.Final.jar**, it seems to conflict with the same class javax.ws.rs.core.Response, but from the library /opt/GlassFish3/glassfish/modules/jersey-core.jar (or some other jar in the **bundles**), which seems to be preferably loaded.

Resulting in the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.readEntity (Ljava / lang / Class;) Ljava / lang / Object;
```

Is it possible to 'force' the load of the **jaxrs-api-3.0.10.Final.jar** library in some way instead of **jersey-core.jar**?

Can you suggest any solution?

(We don't use MAVEN)

Thanks and best regards

Comment: You use a Java EE server which provide stuff for you which you then don’t bring yourself.

Comment: The REST functionality required of our project is only in client mode. Today under Glassfish 3, but in the future in JBoss 8. That's why we try to use server-independent REST libraries. Jersey and RestEasy are giving us difficulties. We are going to try it with CXF.

Comment: In general use the library provided by the server. Develop with the same version and don’t include it in the deployment for that server . Your life will be easier.

Comment: Could you try to disable classloader delegation? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475192/glassfish-where-do-i-set-classloader-delegate-option-to-false